# On Activity result not called and getting error source not found

Tags: android

I have started with the android application development and i facing issue hope i can find solution here:-

I have 2 activity A & B , A calls activity B. In B a table is displayed and on click i want to navigate to activity A and pass the selection made by user in activity B.

here is the code i am using
in Activity A:-

```
     /** listner for playlist button click*/
     btnPlaylist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlayListActivity.class);
                finish( );
                startActivity(i);
            }
```

Using this i succesfully navigate to activity B.

In activity B i have itemclicklistener on which i navigate to activity A:-

```
  private OnItemClickListener musicgridlistener = new OnItemClickListener() 
      {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position,long id) 
            {


                        /** After selecting song go back to main view. */
                        Intent in = new Intent(PlayListActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        in.putExtra( "filename" , filename );
                        finish( );
                        startActivityForResult( in,0 );


            }
      };
```

On Activity A i have onActivityResult to get the result from B:-

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
   {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

     if (requestCode == 0) { 


      }

}
```

**My Issues:-**

****When i run normally ( not in debugging mode) i navigate successfully navigate A->B->A.
but i don't get any result in A****

**When i run in debug mode in emulator the OnActivityResult never gets called instead i get a
error 'Source not found' after below code is executed:-**

```
                Intent in = new Intent(PlayListActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                in.putExtra( "filename" , filename );
                finish( );
                startActivityForResult( in,0 );
```

Thanks in advance,
Vishesh.

Comment: please post logcat stack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing it in a wrong way.. to go from `A` to `B` you should use `startActivityForResult` and then to get back the result use `setResult`

```
/** listner for playlist button click*/
 btnPlaylist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlayListActivity.class);
            finish( );
            startActivityForResult(i, 0);
        }
```

B:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position,long id) 
        {


                    /** After selecting song go back to main view. */
                    Intent in = new Intent(PlayListActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    in.putExtra( "filename" , filename );
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, in);
                    finish( );


        }
```

check http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/12186/android-startactivityforresult-example/

Answer (score 0):

You should use startActivityForResult on activity A to launch activity B. Don't finish A.
In activity B use setResult to return the result, the finish it. The must be something like:

```
    Activity A:

    /** listner for playlist button click*/
    btnPlaylist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlayListActivity.class);

            startActivityForResult(i);
        } 

    Activity B:
    /** After selecting song go back to main view. */
        Intent in = new Intent(PlayListActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        in.putExtra( "filename" , filename );

        setResult(RESULT_OK, in);
        finish();

    }
};
```

Regards.

Comment: Yes i was doing it the wrong way.. I finally got the solution.